# Separating numbers through split function while typing in EditText and saving into Arrays in Android

Tags: java, arrays, split

I need to separate numbers from an EditText while typing (OnTextChangedListner)

EditText data will be like 1-3-2-0

With split function, I would like to save each numbers separated by "-" in separate array, I've done this, but when i start typing in EdtTxtInput5, application crashes.

```
EdtTxtInput5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String rapd = EdtTxtInput5.getText().toString();
            String[] Separated =  rapd.split("-");
            String Ropani = Separated[0];
            String Aana = Separated[1];
            String Paisa = Separated[2];
            String Dam = Separated[3];
            EdtTxtInput1.setText(Ropani);
            EdtTxtInput2.setText(Aana);
            EdtTxtInput3.setText(Paisa);
            EdtTxtInput4.setText(Dam);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*onTextChanged* will be fired even if you type a single character.  This means that your Separated array will have a length of 0. If you try to access it beyond this position it will naturally crash.

If you want to display the parts, do so until you have at least 4 elements.

```
if (Separated.length>=4) ...
```

It should not crash now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great support. It worked, but I want to display separated numbers live; not after completion of all 4 numbers. In this case what should be done?

Comment: @Dmandar you can update EdtTxtInput1 after length>0, EdtTxtInput2 after length>1 and so on...